# How to set different entry_options for each CollectionType entry in Symfony FormBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder, symfony-2.8

I'm trying to create multiple `HiddenType` fields in with Form Builder using `CollectionType`, to group these fields when I'm dealing with them in my controller. But I want each field to have different attributes. Is it possible to use `entry_options` to set different options for each entry?

I'm using a javascript drag and drop plugin to drop elements in a container, when these elements are dropped a JS code updates these hidden fields that, I use to capture the information in my controller. So is mandatory that these fields are grouped somehow so I can deal with them easily in my controller.

An example:

```
$builder->add(self::FIELD_MAPPED_COLUMNS, CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type'    => HiddenType::class,
    'data'          => ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'],
    'label'         => false,
    'entry_options' => [
        'attr' => [
            'data-my-field' => '?????'
        ]
    ]
])->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
```

I want to set a different `data-my-field` for each `HiddenType` so I can use it in Javascript. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I just faced the same problem. Here is my workaround.

First add a template in the entry_options:

```
$builder->add(self::FIELD_MAPPED_COLUMNS, CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type'    => HiddenType::class,
    'data'          => ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'],
    'label'         => false,
    'entry_options' => [
        'attr' => [
            'data-my-field' => '%templateForMyFieldByFieldData%'
        ]
    ]
])->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
```

Then render each field of the collection individually in a Twig loop and replace the template by the required value:

```
...
{{ (form_widget(field) | replace('%templateForMyFieldByFieldData%', valueToInsert)) | raw }}
...
```

Hopefully it will be usefull to someone !